# Configuring proxy_pass multiple params w/ dynamic route + API call

Tags: nginx, axios, next.js, reverse-proxy, moralis

I need to configure a reverse proxy for a dynamic route that appends a variable `chainId` to an axios request to an outside moralis API. Getting a 502 Bad Gateway.

Server Route Structure

`/moralis/ERC20/${token.address}?chainId=${chainId}`

Route Implementation

```
app.get('/moralis/ERC20/:address', async (req, res) => {
    ...

    try {
      const chainId = req.query.chainId ?? 1;
      const chainIdHex = '0x' + chainId.toString(16);

      const response = await rateLimit.fetchAndRetry(() =>
        rateLimit.acquireToken(req, 'moralis', 3, () =>
          axios.get(
            `https://deep-index.moralis.io/api/v2/erc20/${req.params.address}/price?chain=${chainIdHex}`,
          ),
        ),
      );
     
    }
  });
```

NGINX config

```
    location ~* ^/moralis/ERC20/(.*) {
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4000$request_uri;
    }
```

1. Do I need a reverse proxy for the axios call?
2. Am I actually capturing the entire request_uri?

Comment: To answer my own questions:
1. No
2. Yes. The only reason I wasn't capturing it was a client-side error. Fixing that fixed the route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need neither a regex location, nor a `$request_uri` part. Just use a simple prefix location and do not add anything after the upstream address, your request URI will be passed "as-is":

```
location /moralis/ERC20/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4000;
}
```

**Do not** add the trailing slash after the upstream name! It will be considered as a proxied URI part, completely changing the `proxy_pass` directive behavior. If you have regex locations that could potentially take over that `/moralis/ECR20/...` request URI, you can use a `^~` location modifier:

```
location ^~ /moralis/ERC20/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4000;
}
```

Read [`location`](http://nginx.org/r/location) and [`proxy_pass`](http://nginx.org/r/proxy_pass) directives documentation to find out somewhat more complete explanation, there are not so many words to read.

Comment: Thanks for responding! Are you saying that `(.*)` and `request_uri` is superfluous then?

I ended up fixing an unrelated error that got my config above working. How does my regex differ from yours in practice?

Comment: If you don't specify an URI after the upstream name, current URI and query string (counting all triggered rewrite rules!) will be used for the proxied request. Mine isn't regex but a "prefix location" which is definitely faster, especially for the high-loaded systems.

Comment: @thugzook The general rule for high efficient nginx configs is "whenever you can avoid using regex, avoid it".